# Getting error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED in middle of execution on protractor

Tags: protractor

I am executing my script and I am getting "ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED" error in middle of execution. I am executing 46 it() functions and at 42 my browser gets closed and I get above error on console. I tried starting selenium web driver with "webdriver-manager start --standalone", but it didn't help.
my config file is as below,

```
var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');
var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
dest: 'target/screenshots',
filename: 'Report.html',
reportTitle: 'Execution Report',
showSummary: true,
showQuickLinks: true,

pathBuilder: function(currentSpec, suites, browserCapabilities) {
  // will return chrome/your-spec-name.png
return browserCapabilities.get('browserName') + '/' + currentSpec.fullName;
 }});

exports.config = {

directConnect: true,
//seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
capabilities: {'browserName': 'firefox'},
// multiCapabilities: [
//  {
//      browserName: 'firefox'
//    }, 
//    {
//      browserName: 'chrome'
//    }
//    ],

framework: 'jasmine',
specs: ['Login_spec2.js','Auction_spec.js'],

allScriptsTimeout: 5000000,
getPageTimeout: 5000000,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 5000000
},

    // Setup the report before any tests start
   beforeLaunch: function() {
   return new Promise(function(resolve){
    reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
  });
   },
   // Close the report after all tests finish
   afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    reporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
  });
   },

onPrepare: function() {
    var width = 1300;
    var height = 1200;
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width,height);
    //browser.driver.get(browser.baseUrl);
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
    afterAll(function(done) {
        process.nextTick(done);
    })
}
};
```

My it() function at which I encounter this problem is as below,

```
it('42: Navigate to Followed section and verify that the accepted auction is displayed on the page.', function() {
    FuncLib.SelectSubMenu.get(2).click(); //Click on New Auction Sub-menu
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(Auction.AuctionTitleOnDetails), 20000);
        var MyFollowedAuction = Auction.AuctOnMyAuctions.filter(function(MyAuction){
            var Title = MyAuction.element(by.css('.title.ng-binding')).getText();
            return protractor.promise.all([Title]).then(function(result){
                return result[0].trim() == data.AuctionName;
            })
        }).last();
        expect(MyFollowedAuction.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
        expect(MyFollowedAuction.element(by.repeater('file in auction.AuctionFiles')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
        MyFollowedAuction.element(by.repeater('file in auction.AuctionFiles')).click();
        browser.sleep(2000);

});
```

Console Log is as below,

```
...FF.[14:48:50] E/launcher - Error code: 135
[14:48:50] E/launcher - Error message: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:61964
[14:48:50] E/launcher - Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:61964
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/rohitgathibandhe/npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:381:15)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:308:9)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at emitErrorNT (net.js:1271:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
From: Task: WebDriver.takeScreenshot()
at Driver.schedule (/Users/rohitgathibandhe/npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:377:17)
at Driver.takeScreenshot (/Users/rohitgathibandhe/npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:972:17)
at ProtractorBrowser.to.(anonymous function) [as takeScreenshot] (/Users/rohitgathibandhe/npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:60:29)
at /Users/rohitgathibandhe/node_modules/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter/index.js:437:25
at /Users/rohitgathibandhe/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3073:15
at baseForOwn (/Users/rohitgathibandhe/node_modules/lodash/index.js:2046:14)
at /Users/rohitgathibandhe/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3043:18
at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/rohitgathibandhe/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3346:13)
at Jasmine2ScreenShotReporter.specDone (/Users/rohitgathibandhe/node_modules/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter/index.js:435:9)
at dispatch (/Users/rohitgathibandhe/npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1966:28)
[14:48:50] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
```

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace from the console. That helps to debug the issue easier.

Comment: Nit: Please properly format your code this is difficult to follow. This is hard to look at. Also, I'm not sure which line 42 is. Questions: does this work if the browser is only in Chrome? What is the console output if you just focus this test? What do the supporting files that create Auction and FuncLib look like? Another item of concern: I'm not sure that is how filter works. Please see the API http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter.

Comment: I have added the console log.